# Python Import Linux vs Windows

Tags: python, import, operating-system, cross-platform

I am developping a new little project which need to run on Windows **and** Linux. To explain my problem I will use 3 files.

parser/__init__.py

```
from .toto import Parser as TotoParser
```

parser/toto.py

```
class Variable(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return "totoVariable"

class Parser(object):
    @staticmethod
    def parse(data):
        return Variable()
```

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from parser import TotoParser

def main():
    print(TotoParser.parse(""))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In this project. I create several modules(file) into different packages(directory). The thing is I need to change the name of module imported. To do that I use aliasing into __init__ files.
My project run perfectly on Lunix but when I tried it on Windows this problem occurs !

> ImportError: cannot import name 'TotoParser'

Sorry for my English, I am learning it...

Comment: In main.py, can you not just do "from parser import toto" (leaving the init file empty)?

Answer (score 0):

Please rename init.py to __init__.py, I believe that it is work, case already named as __init__.py ignore this anwser...

Comment: year I just put init.py because of markdown language. it underline the init word...